# Text goes past footer

Tags: html, css

I'm currently creating a site for a few friends & my text goes past my footer whenever I use

past it. I have included the HTML and CSS file, I can't seem to solve my issue. That may be because I'm fairly new to all of this but I'm willing to learn. I was the footer to say in place while the page scrolls and the text can freely go down the page without having the footer stay in place and overlapping the text. Thanks guys!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: pricedown;
  src: url('fonts/pricedown.TTF');
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}


/*hr {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
}*/

#header-wrapper {
  height: 274px;
  background: url(images/panorama.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

#header-text h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  color: white;
}

#header-text p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  /*position: fixed;*/
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  color: white;
}

#toolbar2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

#search {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  width: 680px;
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#welcomee-message {
  width: 610px;
  height: 70px;
  float: middle;
}

#welcome-message {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1120px;
  float: left;
}

#welcome-message h1 {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message p {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message h1 {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message p {
  color: white;
}

#statistics {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

#statistics h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#statistics p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#contact {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

#contact h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#contact p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#information-center {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
}

#information-center p {
  color: white;
}

#first-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 470px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#first-post h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#first-post h2 {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#first-post p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#first-post a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#second-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 440px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#second-post h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#second-post h2 {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#second-post p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#second-post a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  overflow: auto
}

#footer-text {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#menu2 {
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu2 ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

#menu2 li {
  float: left;
}

#menu2 a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  color: white;
}

#copyrights {
  float: right;
}

#copyrights p {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#changelog {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#changelog h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#changelog p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}


/*#changelog hr{
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
}*/

#post {
  width: 475px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

#post p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#welcome-message-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#welcome-message-post h1 {
  color: white;
}


/*#comments {
 width: 400px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid white;
} 

#comments h2{
 font-size: 14px;
 color: white;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#profile-picture {
 width: 50px;
 height: 20px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 background-color:white;
}

#profile-picture {
 width: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#profile-name {
 width: 0px;
 float: right;
 padding-left: 20px;
} 

#profile-name  p{
 font-size: 14px;
 color: white;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <title>Roleplay Server of Kane </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="toolbar">

        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ucp</a></li>
            <li><a href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="toolbar2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="welcomee-message">
        <center>
          <h1>General Website Changelog</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div id="information-center">


      </div>
      <div id="changelog">
        <h1> Version 1.0 - 15.09.2017</h1>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        < </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
      <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-text">

          <div id="menu2">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ucp</a></li>
              <li class="current_page_item"><a href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="copyrights">
            <p>---- Roleplay © 2017 - Code and Design by Hazard </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove height to all these classes and test it

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v1p9f61/1/)

```
    #changelog {
        width: 500px;
        /* height: 500px; */
    }
    #information-center {
        width: 250px;
        /* height: 500px; */
        float: right;
    }
    #content {
        width: 680px;
        /* height: 1200px; */
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
```

and your html structure was not in a proper way try to validate it

Comment: "and your html structure was not in a proper way try to validate it" What does this mean? Genuinely curious, fairly new so I'll take any advice for the future and to fix up & clean up my code

Comment: i copied your html `dody` in jsfiddle(i added in the answer)and i see some `div` are nor properly closed.

Comment: If  this answer works, please mark it as answer so others get benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove height.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: pricedown;
  src: url('fonts/pricedown.TTF');
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}

#header-wrapper {
  height: 274px;
  background: url(images/panorama.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

#header-text h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  color: white;
}

#header-text p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

#toolbar {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  /*position: fixed;*/
}

#menu {
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  color: white;
}

#toolbar2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
}

#search {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#welcomee-message {
  width: 610px;
  height: 70px;
  float: middle;
}

#welcome-message {
  width: 110px;
  height: 1120px;
  float: left;
}

#welcome-message h1 {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message p {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message h1 {
  color: white;
}

#welcomee-message p {
  color: white;
}

#statistics {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

#statistics h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#statistics p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#contact {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

#contact h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#contact p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#information-center {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
}

#information-center p {
  color: white;
}

#first-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 470px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#first-post h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#first-post h2 {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#first-post p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#first-post a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#second-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 440px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

#second-post h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#second-post h2 {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#second-post p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#second-post a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  background: url(images/tb-bg.png) repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;
  overflow: auto
}

#footer-text {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#menu2 {
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu2 ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

#menu2 li {
  float: left;
}

#menu2 a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  color: white;
}

#copyrights {
  float: right;
}

#copyrights p {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#changelog {
  width: 500px;
}

#changelog h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#changelog p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#post {
  width: 475px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

#post p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#welcome-message-post {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#welcome-message-post h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <title>Roleplay Server of Kane </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ucp</a></li>
            <li><a href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="toolbar2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="welcomee-message">
        <center>
          <h1>General Website Changelog</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div id="information-center">
      </div>
      <div id="changelog">
        <h1> Version 1.0 - 15.09.2017</h1>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>

        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;">
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer-text">
        <div id="menu2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ucp</a></li>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="changelog.html">Changelog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="copyrights">
          <p>---- Roleplay © 2017 - Code and Design by Hazard </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```